# Unicode/special characters in help_text for Django form?

Tags: django-models, character-encoding, python-unicode

I am trying to add a special character (specifically the ndash) to a Model field's `help_text`. I'm using it in the Form output so I tried what seemed intuitive for the HTML:

```
help_text='2 &ndash; 30 characters'
```

Then I tried:

```
help_text='2 \2013 30 characters'
```

Still no luck. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

django escapes all html by default. try wrapping your string in [`mark_safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.safestring)

Comment: That was going to be my fall back. I just wasn't sure if there was something else I was missing. Search of Google and Stackoverflow yielded nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it on your second try. First you need to declare the string as Unicode by prefacing it with a `u`. Second, you wrote the codepoint wrong. It needs a preface as well; like `\u`.

```
help_text=u'2\u201330 characters'
```

Now it will work and has the added benefit of not polluting the string with HTML character entities. Remember that field value could be used elsewhere, not just in the Form display output. This tip is universal for using Unicode characters in Python.

Further reading:

- Unicode [literals](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code) in Python, which mentions other codepoint prefaces (`\x` and `\U`)
- [PEP263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) has simple instructions for using actual raw Unicode characters in a source file.